# Invoke from different thread

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I can't believe it,this works in my other application,but in this one,which has similiar structure - it doesn't!

```
    public string ListAdd
    {
        set
        {
            if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(value);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

The way I call it:

```
        var formz = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;
        if (formz != null)
            formz.ListAdd = "asdasdasdasd";
```

If I call it from the function where I receive packet(I want to put it on the listView) over TCP - Nothing happens,but If I call it in that same class where I initialize WinSock - it works.

Where could the problem be?

**EDIT:**
I just debugged the application ,formz is null at the place I call it(receive function).
Why is it null there,but not at any other place?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing work like that in a property setter, consider changing it to a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think, it will solve your problem, but have you thought about using the following pattern to do the invoke? I consider it much more readable. Create this extension method.

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
   public static void ThreadSafeInvoke(this Control control, MethodInvoker method)
   {
      if (control != null)
      {
         if (control.InvokeRequired)
         {
            control.Invoke(method);
         }
         else
         {
            method.Invoke();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And then you can perform thread safe method calls like this.

```
Form form = new Form();

form.ThreadSafeInvoke(() => form.Text = "ThreadSafeInvoke");
```

Or multiple calls at once.

```
form.ThreadSafeInvoke(() =>                 
{
   form.Text = "ThreadSafeInvoke";
   form.Visible = true;
   form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
});
```

**UPDATE**

So the problem is clearly `Form.ActiveForm` returning `null`.

1. There is no active form at the moment of the call.
2. The thread has no permission to get the active form - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform(loband).aspx) states that [UIPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.uipermission.aspx) is required.

Answer (score 1):

If ActiveForm is returning null then you might not have an active form or it is not of type Form1. You are using "as Form1", so if you have a Form2 which is active then formz will be set to null.

Can you pass formz into the function instead of calling ActiveForm?

Comment: I have only one form,and I use async(WSAAsyncSelect()) to do my connections.

No,I cant assign Form1 to a var that hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: So what does Form.ActiveForm return? Null or a form of a type other than Form1?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are in debug mode; If so, the *active form* value returned will be null.