# ProgressBar resets at 60%

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have this code:

```
for(int k = 0; k<11; k++)
{
    pBar.Maximum = 10;
    pBar.Value = k;
    if (pBar.Maximum == k)
        pBar.Value = 0;
}
```

However, the problem is, the progressbar gets reset when it is about 60% full. How can I ensure that the progressbar will fill all the way before being reset?

Comment: With that code, I'd be surprised if it were even visible, as you don't appear to let the message pump run, and render any changes

Comment: What exactly are you doing inside that loop? It doesn't actually look like this, I presume?

Comment: Unfortunately that happens all the time in a themed interface (Windows XP themed and above). If you switch to Classic mode, the progress bar will appear fully filled. I have no idea why it happens, but I suffer from it as well.

Comment: @Groo, I am adding an sql row, based on a list. I used to have it in a foreach loop, but that did not have a current index value.

Comment: @GSerg, that does not happen to me. It does display 1 or higher.

Comment: @GSerg I generally don't condone using Thread.Sleep in a Winforms application.. Even with DoEvents, it can be problematic, and it's much simpler and more elegant (in my opinion) to implement it with a timer.

Comment: @Daniel I solely added DoEvents and Sleep to let the visual effects actually appear in this trivial sample. The posted answers are all about the control not having time to redraw itself, but this is not actually the problem, which I tried to demonstrate.

Comment: @GSerg My bad, I misunderstood and thought that that was the solution you were proposing.

Comment: @GSerg: can you explain a bit better, what exactly happens "all the time"? Are you saying that setting both `Maximum` and `Value` to 10 will make `ProgressBar` show 60%?

Comment: @Groo, I believe that GSerg's problem is that at 1 and 2 the progress bar appears blank.

Comment: @Groo Yes, exactly. Also, when `Minimun = 0` and `Maximum = 10`, the progress bar appears completely empty when `Value = 0`, `1` or `2`. This does not happen if I switch my Windows 7 to the Classic mode or access it via remote desktop. I've suffered from this effect in my apps that involved backrogund workers associated with progress bars, but just accepted it as granted and moved on.

Comment: @Groo But that only happens when you're using a loop, and a next value is set before the painting of the previous value is completed. If I just set `Value = Maximum` without a loop, it fully fills the bar, taking about 1.5 seconds for that. Which doesn't happen in Classics mode, where painting is synchronous.

Comment: @Groo Indeed, the best way to understand something it to try to explain it to someone else :) I think I'll post an answer now.

Comment: Why do people always try to point out how my questions somehow are duplicates?

Comment: @CCInc Don't take it personally. It is beneficial for the community to have links between questions that have exactly same underlying problem. If you seem to get that a lot, it *might* be an indication of you not using search properly, but in this particular case I just can't see how you could find that question with a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem, and wrote about it [here](http://thestrangertech.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-fix-progressbar-not-updating-fast.html). The idea was from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214147/1482644) SO question.

```
     progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
     if (e.ProgressPercentage != 0)
         progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage - 1;
     progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
     if (progressBar1.Maximum == e.ProgressPercentage)
         progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pBar.Maximum = 10;
int count = 0;

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += (source, e) =>
{
    pBar.Value = count;
    if (pBar.Maximum == count)
    {
        pBar.Value = 0;
        timer.Stop();
    }
    count++;
}
timer.Start();
```

Your problem is that you're using a loop. You need to use a timer so that the program has time to both perform the checks/assignments and update the screen.

The code replaces the for loop with a timer that calls the body of the loop. Since a timer does not have an index variable, it is initialized outside of the timer (count) and updated with each tick.

Comment: I doubt that OP really does absolutely nothing inside the loop. This will work, but I wouldn't say it's common to update a progress bar using a timer.

Comment: So, using this, how would I add the code from my original ForEach loop and after each interarion update the progressbar?

Comment: @CCInc Replace the code you have above with the code I provided. If you have anything that you would like to do in the loop, write it inside the Tick method, using count as the index variable.

Comment: Ok, this works, however I am using a Sqlite database, and whenever I access the SqliteConnection inside of the Tick, the connection state is closed, while outside of the tick, it was open. Why is this?

Comment: @CCInc This is probably because the timer is called on a different thread than the connection, meaning that by the time the timer is called, the connection is already closed - is it possible for you to open the SqliteConnection inside of the timer? Also, where is the code that closes the connection? Maybe you can move it into the timer.

Comment: @CCInc I edited my code to provide a timer.Stop() method, which should always be done - my bad for not including it originally. You could move the close connection code to the if clause.

Answer (score 2):

First: there is no any reason to assign `pBar.Maximum` on *every interarion*.
Just do:

```
pBar.Maximum = 10;
for(int k = 0; k<11; k++)
{
   pBar.Value = k;
   if (pBar.Maximum == k)
      pBar.Value = 0;
}
```

Second: your code result in *blocking* iteration. There is no way it could ever behave correctly. Use multi-threading and change the progress `value` based on some `event`,`tick` whatever, not in loop, as it's done here.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to Classic mode, this glitch will be gone. The progress bar will appear fully drawn before being reset.

This is because in Classic mode, the painting operation is synchronous and completes before the `Value` setter returns, but in the themed mode, there is some sort of animation played when you increase the value, and that takes some time to play.

On contrary, when you decrease the value, there is no animation; the progress bar is shrinked immediately.

This is why it appears only about 60% full: you decrease the value (which completes immediately) before the progress bar has time to draw the animation for the last several increments.