# Return things from function to bgWorker c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

Edit for better understanding...

I have a Form1.cs file and a separate Class.cs file.

In `Form1` I have a bgWorker that calls Class.myFunc(), this does three `foreach` loops, each loop return some values such as `string ClientName`, or `string ClientOrder`.

I want to return these values from Class.myFunc to bgWorker (which is inside `Form1`, remember) and insert them into a ListView, Textbox, or whatever.

So the problem is: How I return string values from Class.myFunc to BgWorker?

I hope someone can help me with this...

Form1.cs

```
void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ControlsHelper.ControlInvike(listProcess, () => listProcess.Items.Add("Current").Name = "item1");
            myOtherClass cp = new myOtherClass();
            cp.myFunc();
}
```

Class.cs

```
public void myFunc()
{
    foreach (string Client in Clients)
    {
           // Do something
           // Return Client and insert into listview, richtextbox, W/E
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you could just pass the "listview" into the function and have the function insert the values.

Comment: @Sam.Rueby: Wouldn't work because the BackgroundWorker is running on a different thread than the UI thread.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oh- the question was difficult to understand.

Comment: I've edited the question, I hope now is easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Daniel Hilgarth's answer: if the BGW doesn't exist in the context of `Class.cs` can you not pass it in as a parameter so that you can update your progress. In your DoWork signature the `object sender` is the BGW you want to cast as BackgroundWorker to send into `myFunc`.

So you'd have

```
public void myFunc(BackgroundWorker bgw)
{
    foreach (string Client in Clients)
    {
       // Do something
       // Return Client and insert into listview, richtextbox, W/E

       var returningObjects = List<string>();  //I assume this will be a list of strings based on your question.
       returningObjects.Add(ClientName);
       returningObjects.Add(ClientOrder);
       returningObjects.Add(Client3rdThing);

       bgw.ReportProgress(0,returningObjects)
    }
}
```

An even better than using a generic `List<string>` you could make your own class which has all the items you need then you can call them explicitly instead of referring to a list index.

```
void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    ControlsHelper.ControlInvike(listProcess, () => listProcess.Items.Add("Current").Name = "item1");
            myOtherClass cp = new myOtherClass();
            cp.myFunc(bgw);
}
```

Then in your ProgressChanged event handler

```
private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //Set the  e.UserState to whatever you need. It is of type Object.
    var returnedObjects = e.Userstate as List<string>;
    if(returnedObjects != null)
    {
        //do stuff with each of your returnedObjects[i];
    }

}
```

To ensure thread safety I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/788907/726127) extension method for controls. It's really great having this logic wrapped up in an extension method. You don't need to think about the Invoke structure whenever you need to call it, you just call it.

And be sure to tie it all together when you instantiate your BackgroundWorker using

```
bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgWorker_ProgressChanged);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for... But I have a problem, how can I return e.UserState as an array? I have three values that I want to insert to the listview, how can I use e.UserState[0]-e.UserState[1]-e.UserState[2]

Comment: See my update. Just know that you can pass anything through the `UserState` object because it is of type `object`. Just be sure to cast it appropriately when you use it.

Comment: Sorry, I made it a `List` and not an `Array` but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Yep, that was actually what I did and it worked ;) But I have the same problem I had at the start... ListView adds one row for every foreach on myfunc... It must be only one row, updating the elements while myFunc is running, not adding new rows >.<
`if (obj != null)
            {
                ControlExtension.ThreadSafeInvoke(listProcess, () => listProcess.Items.Add("Item Title").SubItems.AddRange(obj));
            }`

Comment: hmmm are you able to add your `obj` to your listview manually? i.e. can you make a little test method to do all this necessary stuff without any of the complexity of threading? If you can get it to be added there then it should be easy to port it over to this threaded scenario. Anything more than that I'd need to have Visual Studio in front of me (which I don't have right now)

Comment: This is what I did and it's working as I wanted :)



**On Form1() I declared this**
`string[] blank = { "", "", "" };
            listProcess.Items.Add("Row 1").SubItems.AddRange(blank);`



**On ProgressChanged I did this**
`ControlExtension.ThreadSafeInvoke(listProcess, () => listProcess.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = obj[0]);
                ControlExtension.ThreadSafeInvoke(listProcess, () => listProcess.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text = obj[1]);
                ControlExtension.ThreadSafeInvoke(listProcess, () => listProcess.Items[0].SubItems[3].Text = obj[2]);
`

^^

Answer (score 1):

You could (ab)use [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) for this and pass your values as the second parameter.

Comment: as far as I know (so, not much) I can't access to BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress from other class file, because it doesn't exists on the current context...

Comment: @user1381537: This sentence is quite hard to understand. Please edit your question with some sample code.

Comment: Done, I've edited with the bgworker dowork code, and myfunc code

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you really need multi threading.  You may well be able to ge by with just preventing the GUI from updating until the list load is complete.

If you do need multi threading, make sure your three loops are required to run in that order.  If they aren't, then you want 3 bgWorkers instead of 1.

Finally, there are a lot of good articles on thread safety.  You will find that you cannot directly update the listviews, you will have to use thread safe delegates.

Comment: I'm using safe delegates, i've already created a class and function for that.

I need multithreading and it must be 3 loops, one loop inside other loop inside other loop, it must be that way, i've already done this in other languages, but not C# with multithreading..

Comment: The way you have explained this, the myFunc method is running on the same thread as bgWorker.  To get value back to bgWorker, you would just make the return type string or List<string> instead of void.  That part is easy, compared to getting the value from a bgWorker into a GUI component.